# How to set drawing order of images on canvas in react/next javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, next.js, html5-canvas

Example:

```
var image1 = new Image();
image1.src = image1src.png;
var image2 = new Image();

var canvas = mycanvas.current;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var image1.onload = () => {
  ctx.drawImage(image1, 0, 0);
}
var image2.onload = () => {
  ctx.drawImage(image2, 0, 0);
}
```

Sometimes image2 happens to be loaded first and is below image1. I have several images and I need to guarantee the drawing order, what do I do?

Answer (score -2):

Start loading the second Image after the first image is complete

```
var image1.onload = () => {
   var image2.onload = () => {
     ctx.drawImage(image2, 0, 0);
   }
  ctx.drawImage(image1, 0, 0);
}
```